# jquery function executing without the event happening

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-resize

I have a few functions that are executed immediately

```
function calcTheSize() {
  console.log("exec 1")
};
calcTheSize();

function setImages() {
  console.log("exec 2")
};
setImages();
```

I also want them to run on a resize event like this

```
$window.resize(function() {
  calcTheSize();
  setImages();
});
```

The problem is I am getting

> exec 1
>   exec 2
>   exec 1
>   exec 2
>   exec 1
>   exec 2

without any resizing

Comment: Unable to replicate: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/7w6c0nk4/. What you describe cannot happen without something triggering the event

Answer (score 2):

The window resize might be executed because you have your console open, scrolled, or an overflow (scrollbar) is added/removed. In any case, events like these should be registered when the DOM has finished loading.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) { // or use $(function() { ... }
    $(window).on("resize", (e) {
        calcTheSize();
        setImages();
    }
}
```